# Powershell create New-LocalUser from CSV file cannot convert string to securestring

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to create some Local users (Windows 10) from a CSV file, in PowerShell.
I'm using the New-LocalUser, not Net User or ADSI, but getting a Cannot bind parameter "Password" Cannot convert the "P@ssW0rd" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
When search google I can see that i can use convert and -AsSecureString, but that's with a Read-Host, I'm getting the data from a CSV file.

My code is:

```
New-LocalGroup -Name "tester" -Description "for 10 users"
Import-Csv C:\users.csv |
ForEach-Object {
New-LocalUser -Name $_.userName -Password $_.Password
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "tester" -Member $_.userName -add}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to convert the plaintext password to SecureString:

Change this line:

```
New-LocalUser -Name $_.userName -Password ($_.Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Comment: Thx. Avshalom it was helping me a lot :-)
And then I needed to delete the -add then it's also worked with the Add-LocalGroup Member.

Thx.

Comment: May be a bit simpler: run this first then use $secureStringPassword instead of $password `$secureStringPassword = ($password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)`